# MSN Messenger error 80072745

Tags: windows-live-messenger

Every now and then I am unable to login to MSN messenger and I get error code 80072745.

> "We were unable to sign you in to the MSN Messenger, possibly because of a problem with your Internet connection. Please try again later. 80072745"

The solution to this is to do a full reboot and it works fine, but I don't understand why and I'm trying to get to the bottom of it. This has happened to me on two different machines running Windows 7 in two separate locations 50 miles apart using different ISPs, so I don't believe it to be a networking issue.

Some googling reveals that most people blame anti-virus, but I'm using AVG Anti-Virus on one machine and Windows Security Essentials on the other, so I'm not entirely sure that's it either.

Comment: Is your internet connection otherwise OK at those times?

Comment: Completely, no problems whatsoever at those times.